# why is my rock,paper game not running correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning front end and this project for a rock paper game is killing me, I'm not getting any errors and the logic seems correct to me but I'm not getting any output. I think my buttons are wrong and maybe I'm but I honestly have no clue id really appreciate it if somebody could help me out I have been stuck on this for hours.

```
<script>

const score=document.querySelector("score");
const buttons=document.querySelectorAll("buttons");
const computer=document.querySelector("computer");
const player=document.querySelector("player");
const rock=document.getElementById("rock");
const paper=document.getElementById("paper");
const scisscors=document.getElementById("scisscors");


function computerplayer(){
    let computer=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let random=['rock',"paper",'sisscors']
    if(computer>3){
        return 'rock'
    }
    if(computer<2){
        return 'paper'
    }

    else{
        return 'sisscors'
    }
}

function game(choice,computer){
    if(choice=='rock'&& computer=='sisscors'){      
        pscore++
        score();
        console.log( 'u win');
    }

    if(choice== 'rock'&& computer==="rock"){
        console.log("it be a tie")
    }
    if(choice=="rock"&& computer=="paper"){
        cscore++
        score();
        console.log("u lose");
    }

    if(choice== 'sisscors'&& computer=='rock'){
        console.log( "u lost")
        cscore++
        score();
    }
    if(choice=='sisscors'&& computer=='paper'){
        console.log('you win')
        pscore++
        score();
    }
    if(choice=='paper'&& computer=='rock'){
        console.log("you win")
        pscore++
        score();
    }
    if(choice=='paper'&& computer=='sisscors'){
        console.log("lost")
        cscore++
        score();
    }
}

function score(){
    if(pscore==3){
        console.log("end game win")
    }
    if(cscore==3){
        console.log("end game loser")
    }
}

buttons.addEventListener('click', function(){
    game('rock')
})
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(){
    game('paper')
})
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(){
    game('sisscors')
})
 
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Fun fact: scissors is spelled "scissors", not "sisscors" or "scisscors"

Comment: for querySelector and querySelectorAll, have you miss the . or #?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this code won't return 3 or greater number

```
let computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
```

then computerplayer() will only return 'paper' and 'sisscors' and you should change computerplayer() function.

Next you should change your buttons event listennr to these:

```
rock.addEventListener('click', function () {
    game('rock', computerplayer())

})
paper.addEventListener('click', function () {
    game('paper', computerplayer())
})
rock.addEventListener('click', function () {
    game('sisscors', computerplayer())
})
```

Since you have to change many more things, then I mentioned a complete code here:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let pscore = 0;
        let cscore = 0;

        const result = document.querySelector(".result");
        const player = document.querySelector(".pscore");
        const computer = document.querySelector(".cscore");

        const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
        const paper = document.getElementById("paper");
        const scissors = document.getElementById("scissors");

        rock.addEventListener('click', function () {
            game('rock', computerplayer())
        })
        paper.addEventListener('click', function () {
            game('paper', computerplayer())
        })
        scissors.addEventListener('click', function () {
            game('scissors', computerplayer())
        })


        function computerplayer() {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            if (random == 0)
                return 'rock'
            else if (random == 1)
                return 'paper'
            else if (random == 2)
                return 'scissors'
        }

        function game(choice, computerAction) {
            if (choice == 'rock' && computerAction == 'scissors') {
                pscore++
                score();
                console.log('u win');
            } else if (choice == 'rock' && computerAction === "rock") {
                console.log("it be a tie")
            } else if (choice == "rock" && computerAction == "paper") {
                cscore++
                score();
                console.log("u lose");
            } else if (choice == 'scissors' && computerAction == 'rock') {
                console.log("u lost")
                cscore++
                score();
            } else if (choice == 'scissors' && computerAction == 'paper') {
                console.log('you win')
                pscore++
                score();
            } else if (choice == 'scissors' && computerAction === "scissors") {
                console.log("it be a tie")
            } else if (choice == 'paper' && computerAction == 'rock') {
                console.log("you win")
                pscore++
                score();
            } else if (choice == 'paper' && computerAction == 'scissors') {
                console.log("lost")
                cscore++
                score();
            } else if (choice == 'paper' && computerAction === "paper") {
                console.log("it be a tie")
            }

            function score() {
                console.log(pscore, cscore)
                player.innerHTML = pscore;
                computer.innerHTML = cscore;

                if (pscore == 3) {
                    console.log("end game win")
                    result.innerHTML = 'You won.';
                } else if (cscore == 3) {
                    console.log("end game loser")
                    result.innerHTML = 'Computer won.';
                }

                if (pscore == 3 || cscore == 3) {
                    rock.style.display = 'none';
                    paper.style.display = 'none';
                    scissors.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
<body>
    Computer:<span class="cscore"></span>
    <br />
    Player: <span class="pscore"></span><br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="rock" value="Rock" />
    <input type="button" id="paper" value="Paper" />
    <input type="button" id="scissors" value="scissors" />
    <span class="result"></span>
</body>
```